# add email, securityquestion,security answer,simple membership in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am using MVC 4, I am trying to create a user account using simple membership concept.
When I am creating a user account using `membership.CreateUser()` method it throwing below error

*Specified method is not supported.*

***Question #1. How can i resolve the above issue?***

***Question #1. How can I add Email, Security Question, Security Answer fields to the membership?***

This is my existing code in web.config.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">      
  <providers>        
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Below is my code to add user account.

```
private void SeedMembership()
    {

        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        var roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
        var membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
if (membership.GetUser("sridharnetha", false) == null)
        {
            MembershipCreateStatus status;
            membership.CreateUser("sridharnetha", "xxxxx", "sridhar@abc.com", "what is your favariote color", "test", false, null, out status);
        }
        if (!roles.GetRolesForUser("sridharnetha").Contains("member"))
        {
            roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "sridharnetha" }, new[] { "member" });
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a note on the MSDN documentation for the [SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider.createuser%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

> If the SimpleMembershipProvider class has been initialized using a call to the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() method, ***this method is not supported and will throw a NotSupportedException exception***. However, if the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection() method has not been called, and if you have configured your site to use the standard ASP.NET membership provider, this method is passed through to the standard membership provider. For more information, see the SimpleMembershipProvider class overview.

You need to customize your UserProfile class with the properties you want, such as email. Here is an [article on how to customize and seed SimpleMembership](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).